# How to add icon inside textfield

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have added icon to textfield using `icon: Icon(Icons.mail),` however it appears outside the textfield.

How can the position of icon be changed so that it is displayed inside the textfield.

TextField:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `prefixIcon` attribute instead of `icon` like

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail)),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**PrefixIcon:**

> An icon that appears before the prefixText and before the
>   editable part of the text field, within the decoration's container.

Below code will work for question

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
  ),
);
```

If we want to arrange icon with some padding we can do like:

```
 prefixIcon: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 30.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm), // Change this icon as per your requirement
        )
```

Comment: What if you want it at the end of the text field, and not before the text? can that be done?